# h:link in JavaServer Faces

Tags: jsf, hyperlink

I’m trying to add link in jsf:

```
<h:link value="#{msgs.addproject}" styleClass="addBtn" outcome="/ profile/addproject.xhtml" />
```

But in page source i get only this:

```
<span class="addBtn">Add project</span>
```

Where can be problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `outcome` does not evaluate to a proper link JSF renders a `<span>` tag instead. Check your `/ profile/addproject.xhtml` whether it is correct(there is a space before profile).